# How do I have eth0 use the global DNS settings?

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

No matter what I try, `eth0` never budges from the DHCP DNS settings.

This is the result I get from `sudo resolvectl status --no-pager`

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes                 
      DNSSEC setting: yes                 
    DNSSEC supported: yes                 
  Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1             
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1             
                      1.0.0.1             
                      2606:4700:4700::1111
                      2606:4700:4700::1001
          DNS Domain: ~.                  

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes        
      DNSSEC setting: yes        
    DNSSEC supported: yes        
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.4.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.4.1

Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes 
      DNSSEC setting: yes 
    DNSSEC supported: yes 

Link 4 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes 
      DNSSEC setting: yes 
    DNSSEC supported: yes
```

Note that `eth0` is using `192.168.4.1`.

I have tried adding:

```
[Network]
UseDNS=false
[DHCP]
UseDNS=false
[DHCPv4]
UseDNS=false
[DHCPv6]
UseDNS=false
[IPv6AcceptRA]
UseDNS=false
```

To `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`, `/etc/systemd/networkd.conf`, `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

I have tried any which combination of the following:

- `sudo resolvectl reset-server-features`
- `sudo resolvectl revert eth0`
- `sudo systemd-resolve --set-dns=1.1.1.1 --interface=eth0`
- `sudo resolvectl dns eth0 1.1.1.1`
- `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd`
- `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`
- `sudo resolvectl flush-caches --no-pager`
- `sudo resolvectl status --no-pager`
- `sudo systemd-resolve --statistics`

Here is the current `cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
# 
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[DHCP]
UseDNS=false

[DHCPv4]
UseDNS=false

[DHCPv6]
UseDNS=false

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
DNS=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111 2606:4700:4700::1001
DNSSEC=true
DNSOverTLS=true
```

What am I missing, I've gone through hundreds of tabs and internet searches, and I can't figure it out.

System is `Ubuntu 20.10 (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-1029-raspi aarch64`

Answer (score 1):

Seems doing `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd` resets the DNS configuration that can be applied via `sudo resolvectl dns eth0 1.1.1.1`.

As such, the restarts should be done after configuration FILE changes, and flushes and status checks should be done after API changes.

That said, the best I can get is the following:

```
Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                 
DefaultRoute setting: no                  
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes                 
      DNSSEC setting: yes                 
    DNSSEC supported: yes                 
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.4.1         
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1             
                      1.0.0.1             
                      2606:4700:4700::1111
                      2606:4700:4700::1001
                      192.168.4.1         
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Which still has the `Current DNS Server` as the DHCP DNS server.

---

Was able to get eth0 to update by doing:

```
sleep 1
sudo ifdown "$interface"
sleep 1
sudo ifup "$interface"
sleep 1
```